# Chromecast Android: How to disconnect current device when another device connects to chromecast?

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

So I created a media player app, similar to the Chromecast-Demo-App.

My message stream is a MediaProtocolMessageStream.

When my device (device A) connects to chromecast, it shows that it is connected. However, when another device (device B) connects to chromecast, device A (now expired) is still showing a connection (media route button showing connected).

I see that the tic tac toe activity handles this by sending messages to the receiver, and disconnecting the receiver sends a disconnect message. This is handled inside `onMessageReceived()` in the tic tac toe app's GameMessageStream.

Since onMessageReceived is declared final in the MediaProtocolMessageStream, how do I add this functionality into my app?

Do I need two message streams on separate channels? If so, how can I have them running concurrently?